# solution for smb protocol vulnerability

Tags: protocols, smb

The problem is not programming.
I'm using an old machine, and microsoft stopped patches for those machines.
Does any one have a solution for the SMB protocol vulnerability that use port 445, which is known for attackers ?
Any tricky solution ?
In other words, I want to use the SMB and I cant change the machines becuse it is too expensive.

Answer (score 5):

Get third-party SMB stack. MoSMB has one for sure and there are others to select from. Some support Windows, some are Linux only.

http://mosmb.com

In general I'd reconsider what you're doing: lack of patches, EOSL & so on is a big red flag for having something in production. Unless absolutely necessary of course.

Answer (score 2):

Then you should check if you are vulnerable with this tool from ESET :https://help.eset.com/eset_tools/ESETEternalBlueChecker.exe

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft stopped patches for software, not for your machine ;-)
If you use Xp (i think that's your OS) you cand look on the net for "KB4012598" security patches!

Comment: thanks :),  but In fact I'm using windows 2000, and i think there is no existing patches for it.

Comment: i was thinking about using another port on the request, and then mapping it when it arrives to the software(windows ). Does any 3rd-party softwares make such mapping ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NQE server for Windows